# My anchor test is not working in test.js, invalid argument error

Tags: rust, blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

When I am running an anchor test, I am getting the following error, of invalid arguments. Funnily enough, the crowdFundingPlatform argument it says is missing, is never in any of the code I wrote, as you can see below this error in my anchor files.

```
CrowdFunding
    1) Is initialized!


  0 passing (22ms)
  1 failing

  1) CrowdFunding
       Is initialized!:
     Error: Invalid arguments: crowdFundingPlatform not provided.
```

Here is the JS test:

```
describe("CrowdFunding", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.CrowdFunding;

  const platform = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  it('Is initialized!', async () => {

    const crowd_funding_platform = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    await program.rpc.initialize(
      "limk",
      "description",
      "title",
      new anchor.BN(1),
      {
        accounts: {
          crowd_funding_platform: crowd_funding_platform.publicKey,
          authority: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
          system_program: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        },
        signers: [crowd_funding_platform],
      })

    const PlatformAccount = await program.account.crowd_funding_platform.fetch(crowd_funding_platform.publicKey);
    console.log(PlatformAccount);

  });
})
```

Here is the smart contract framework for the initialize function, as you can see, there is no 'crowdFundingPlatform'

```
pub fn initialize(
        ctx: Context<Initialize>,
        Image: String,
        Description: String,
        Title: String,
        Donation_Goal: u64,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        let campaign = &mut ctx.accounts.crowd_funding_platform;
        campaign.Image = Image;
        campaign.Description = Description;
        campaign.Title = Title;
        campaign.Amount_Donated = 0;
        campaign.Donation_Goal = Donation_Goal;
        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
    init, 
    payer = authority, 
    space = size_of::<CrowdFundingPlatform>() + 8,
    seeds = [b"crowd_funding_platform".as_ref()],
    bump
    )]
    pub crowd_funding_platform: Account<'info, CrowdFundingPlatform>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace crowd_funding_platform and system_program with crowdFundingPlatform and systemProgram in js file.
Here is full js code:

```
describe("CrowdFunding", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.CrowdFunding;

  const platform = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  it('Is initialized!', async () => {

    const [crowdFundingPlatform] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress([Buffer.from("crowd_funding_platform")], program.programId);

    await program.methods.initialize(
        "limk",
        "description",
        "title",
        new anchor.BN(1)
      )
      .accounts({
        crowdFundingPlatform,
        authority: program.provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .rpc();


    const PlatformAccount = await program.account.crowdFundingPlatform.fetch(crowdFundingPlatform.publicKey);
    console.log(PlatformAccount);

  });
})
```